# Variables values remain in memory after Spring Batch Job execution

Tags: spring, variables, memory, execution

My project has several processes that are been executed each day. The problem I found is that after a job execution, when I execute again the same process (with different job parameters, of course) I see Spring batch generates a new Job instance BUT the variables values remain in memory for the new execution.

How is it possible? New instances don't create new Java instances? Problem configuration?

My JobLoader configuration:

```
<bean id="jobLoader" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.AutomaticJobRegistrar">
    <property name="applicationContextFactories">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean">
            <property name="resources" value="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/batch/jobs/*.xml" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jobLoader">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultJobLoader">
            <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you just clear the variables manually each time you start the script?

Comment: Yes, I do it, but I was thinking if there is a better way for designing batch processes.

Comment: My "problem" was that my ItemReader, ItemProcessor are both Spring beans and by default, the scope is Singleton (only one instance).